# QNeat3 Polygons do not finish calculating interpolation

Tags: qgis-plugins, interpolation, matplotlib, isochrone

I have been using QGIS for a couple of years and used QNEAT3 for the first time around one year ago. I never had any problem with it but, after some months not using it, I tried to use it again to calculate some walksheds but the algorithm just doesn't finish (sometimes).

I have a line layer representing sidewalks + point layers representing different services. All the layers are in the same CRS and encoding but, for some reason, some point layers work and some others (most of them) just don't. I really haven't found any rule or coincidence for those that don't work, as the parameters and features are always the same. I have even tried coping points from layers not working into layers that work and they stop working, also I have uploaded the layer spatial index each time.

The problem is, when I try to start the algorithm, the screen just keeps charging when it gets to "Calculating Iso-Interpolation-Raster using QGIS TIN-Interpolator...". I've tried waiting for hours and hours and it never does finish. I do not know what it can be and would be glad if any of you had any idea of what I could do. Also, matplotlib is installed and updated.